# Making dynamically loaded values available in an Angular library

Tags: angular, typescript, dynamic, module, angular-library

I have an Angular application that uses a library. I want to configure the library with some configuration values that are dynamically loaded with a http call by the application (and thus not available at compile time).

What's the best approach for this? Thanks!

I have tried the following methods, but each of them seem to have significant downsides:

## A. LibraryModuleA.forRoot(provider: Provider)

I created a forRoot method on a module in the lib that takes a provider argument and then used an Injection token to make the configuration injectable in the library.

The downside of this approach is that the module that wants to use the library needs to know a lot in order to get it to work.

Library module:

```js
@NgModule({
  // omitted for brevity
})
export class LibraryModuleA{
  static forRoot(provider: Provider): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: LibraryModuleA,
      providers: [provider]
    };
  }
}
```

Client module that uses the library module:

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    LibraryModuleA.forRoot({
      provide: LIBRARY_CONFIGURATION,
      useFactory: (coreState: CoreState): LibraryConfiguration =>
        new LibraryConfiguration(coreState.config1$.value, coreState.config2$.value),
      deps: [CoreState]
    })
  ],
  // omitted for brevity
```

As you can see, the client module needs to create a `LibraryConfiguration` object and it needs to inject that under the `LIBRARY_CONFIGURATION` token. This seems like too much responsibility for the client of the library to me.

## B. LibraryModuleA.forRoot(config1: string, config2: string) and a global singleton

I created a global singleton where I store the configuration values on and I I created a forRoot method on a module in the lib that takes the configuration as a paramter and then use an Injection token to make the configuration injectable in the library.

The downside of this is that I now have a global singleton, which is never a good idea to have and could be the cause of future issues.

Library module:

```js
@NgModule({
  // omitted for brevity
})
export class LibraryModuleA {
  static forRoot(config1: string, config2: string): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: LibraryModuleA ,
      providers: [
        {
          provide: LIBRARY_CONFIGURATION,
          useValue: new LibraryConfiguration(config1, config2)
        }
      ]
    };
  }
```

Global state object:

```js
class GlobalState {
  config1$: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject<ApplicationSettings>('');
  config2$: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject<User>('');
}

const GLOBAL_STATE: GlobalState = new GlobalState ();
export default GLOBAL_STATE;
```

Client module that uses the library module:

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    LibraryModuleA.forRoot(
      GLOBAL_STATE.config1$.getValue(),
      GLOBAL_STATE.config2$.getValue()
    )
  ],
  // omitted for brevity
})
```

## C. LibraryConfigurationService

I created a library configuration service that is available on root level and then I call an init method on this service once after I have retrieved the configuration from the http call.

The downside of this approach is that you must not forget to call the configuration service method if you want to use the library.

Answer (score -1):

this is best way of dynamically loading values use this method

LibraryModuleA.forRoot(config1: string, config2: string) and a global singleton

Comment: Could you please elaborate on why you think that it's the best method?